# CPU Frequency Calculation

Tags: frequency, cpu

I have this in an exercise and it asks me to find the frequency of the CPU. I know how to calculate it for smaller drawings, but how many times does every I-Mem, Add, MUX, ALU, Regs, D-Mem and Control run?

[image]

*I Calculated at about 740MHz but the solution is 783, so this is why i'm asking you.

```
I-Mem = 412ps
Add  =  120ps
MUX  =  21ps
ALU  =  120ps
Regs =  197ps
D-Mem = 351ps
Control=115ps
```

Comment: I think we need chip timings?

Comment: You have to find the critical path for all your implemented instructions, the biggest one will give you the maximum frequency

Comment: As a first guess the instruction lw (load word) has a high propagation delay

Comment: Questions on Stack Exchange sites are resolved by posting and accepting an answer (even if it is your own), not by editing the question.  Your improper edit has been reverted - post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the correct solution is:

[image: Time=Imem+Dmem+ALU+2*Reg]

&

[image: f=1000/Time]

(Which is 0.783 GHz in this case)